# Writing a generic function that can take a Writer as well as an OutputStream

Tags: scala

I wrote a couple of functions that look like this:

```
def myWrite(os: OutputStream) = {}
def myWrite(w: Writer) = {}
```

Now both are very similar and I thought I would try to write a single parametrized version of the function.

I started with a type with the two methods that are common in the Java OutputStream and Writer:

```
type Writable[T] = {
    def close() : Unit
    def write(cbuf: Array[T], off: Int, len: Int): Unit
}
```

One issue is that OutputStream writes `Byte` and Writer writes `Char`, so I parametrized the type with `T`.

Then I write my function:

```
def myWrite[T, A[T] <: Writable[T]](out: A[T]) = {}
```

and try to use it:

```
val w = new java.io.StringWriter()
myWrite(w)
```

Result:

```
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : java.io.StringWriter
 required: ?A[ ?T ]
Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:
 both method any2ArrowAssoc in object Predef of type [A](x: A)ArrowAssoc[A]
 and method any2Ensuring in object Predef of type [A](x: A)Ensuring[A]
 are possible conversion functions from java.io.StringWriter to ?A[ ?T ]
       myWrite(w)
```

I tried a few other combinations of types and parameters, to no avail so far.

My question is whether there is a way of achieving this at all, and if so how.

(Note that the implementation of myWrite will need, internally, to know the type `T` that parametrizes the write() method, because it needs to create a buffer as in new ArrayT.)

UPDATE: The "correct" solution doesn't work because a bug in the compiler: https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/2672

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need to parameterize `A` in `myWrite`.  Your target classes aren't generic!  Second, you don't need to explicitly allow for subclasses--just let inheritance do the trick for you.

```
def myWrite[T](out: Writable[T]) = {}
```

Now the method can infer the type `T`.  As long as you don't for some reason need the true type of `A` also, this will work for you:

```
myWrite(new StringWriter)
```

However, you're going to run into a problem:

```
def myWrite[T](out: Writable[T]) = new Array[T](0)  // Doesn't work!
```

The problem is that this is generic code.  It doesn't know what `T` is--it could be anything!  So you need to tell the compiler to pass in information that identifies `T`:

```
def myWrite[T : ClassManifest](out: Writable[T]) = new Array[T](0)
```

(Edit: simplified the answer to make it actually work.)

---

(Edit: actually, it doesn't quite work--see comments.)

Comment: This still doesn't work though: I get `error: inferred type arguments [Nothing,java.io.FileWriter] do not conform to method myWrite's type parameter bounds [T,A <: Writable[T]]`!

Comment: BTW when you say "it doesn't know what `T` is": as I human I can perfectly infer the type: I notice that Writer corresponds to my Writable, which happens to have a write() method with an Array[Char]. So now I know that I have a Writable[Char]. It seems that at least in a case like this, the type system should be able to infer T. I don't know how the type system works deep down, and if this kind of inference is compatible or not, but as a human I can definitely infer. Anyway while it would be great if it worked out of the box, for now I could settle with implicits if they could be made to work!

Comment: There's a complicated way and a simple way to fix the problem in my original post (I had too much implicit stuff in the REPL at once and got confused about why things worked).  I went for the simple way, which is probably enough.  You can add another wrapper to do it the complicated way if you need the actual type of `A` instead of its superclass `Writable[Char]` or `Writable[Byte]`.

Comment: Thanks Rex, much better! Not sure why the "complicated" version didn't work though.

Comment: I have closed this too early: this compiles but actually using the writer fails at runtime. Try e.g. `def myWrite[T : ClassManifest](out: Writable[T]) = { val a = new Array[T](1); out.write(a, 0, 1)}; val w = new java.io.StringWriter(); myWrite(w)` produces: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.io.StringWriter.write(java.lang.Object, int, int)
 at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1605)
 at .reflMethod$Method1(<console>:6)
 at .myWrite(<console>:6)`

Comment: @ebruchez: Looks like Java arrays are messing things up as they often do.  I'm not sure how to solve that problem in a satisfying way.

Comment: Might be a compiler bug. a.getClass.getName does return [C", which seems to mean the type information is passed properly.

Comment: It turns out to be a bug in the compiler: https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/2672

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
myWrite(w.asInstanceOf[Writable[Char]])
```

...so you would think this would work:

```
implicit def wrToWr(w:java.io.Writer): Writable[Char] = w.asInstanceOf[Writable[Char]]
```

...but it doesn't. I have no idea why not:

```
scala> myWrite(w)
<console>:17: error: type mismatch;
 found   : java.io.StringWriter
 required: Nothing
       myWrite(w)
               ^
```

Where is Nothing coming from??

Comment: You don't need to force the cast using `asInstanceOf`; a simple `myWrite(w: Writable[Char])` should do the trick, since formally `Writable[Char]` acts as a superclass of `Writer` given the type definitions.  Also, `Nothing` comes from the type inference engine using the most specific type possible.  `Nothing` is a subclass of every other class, so it uses that unless forced to do otherwise (and it doesn't realize that it's forced to do otherwise; it thinks it can resolve `T` independently of `A`).

Comment: Ah, that explains a lot. Thanks.